# How to remove gap before first row of UITableView in IOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, storyboard, scrollview

In my UIViewController I have dragged a UITableView which has 2 custom Prototype Cells. Basically Its a accordion.
 When I am loading data on it there always a gap coming between my table view starting position and first row. when I scroll down Its working fine.I have searched in google and find couple of suggestion like

put

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
```

In viewDidLoad OR add This below code in

```
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length,
                                       0.0,
                                       self.bottomLayoutGuide.length,
                                       0.0);
_detailsTableView.contentInset = insets;
```

or

```
 YouStoryboard.storyboard > YouViewController > Attributes inspector > Uncheck - Adjust scroll view insets
```

But none of this worked for me. Here is my UITableView screenshot. Please suggest that how I can remove this gap marked in red.

[image]

After fixing this issue UITableView should looks like

[image]

Inspector Image 1

[image]

Comment: can u upload inspector image , what frame u set for table view

Comment: I have Uploaded Inspector Image. Frame is (20,20,439,239)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing this method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CGFloat height = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    if (section == 0) {
        height = 0.5f;
    }
    return height;
}
```

This will remove the spacing for the first section header. If you want to remove all spacings between sections you can always return 0.5f. Such an odd value is needed because Apple does not allow you to return 0 in this method. (That would have the same effect as not implementing the method at all.) But the value 0.5f will have the desired effect.

Comment: It worked properly . Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: Anybody have any clue how to do this in swift 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I think the space you are trying to get rid of is the header. Use the tableview delegate to set the header on section 0 to a height of 0.

```
tableView:heightForHeaderInSection
```